# Bootstrap "Button Group" Different Color For Each "Active" Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a bootstrap buttongroup in my razor page as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default  btn-na">
        <input id="NA" name="Selection" type="radio" value="NA"> NA
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default  btn-yes">
        <input id="Yes" name="Selection" type="radio" value="Yes"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default  btn-no">
        <input id="No" name="Selection" type="radio" value="No"> No
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default  btn-maybe">
        <input id="Maybe" name="Selection" type="radio" value="Maybe"> Maybe
    </label>
</div>
```

The requirement is make the each button of different color as below (only when they are "selected" / "active"). Not "active" buttons get the default bootstrap color:

```
btn-na -> blue (only when active)
btn-yes -> green (only when active)
btn-no -> red (only when active)
btn-maybe -> yellow (only when active)
```

**UPDATE 1:**
After getting idea from @juzraai, my updated scss file is as follows which is unfortunately lengthy and not "DRY" as I was hoping for. I have overridden bootstrap so the "selected" / "active" button is of different color:

```
.btn-na:active,
.btn-na.active,
.btn-na:active:focus,
.btn-na:active.focus,
.btn-na.active:focus,
.btn-na.active.focus
{
    background-color: #00ace6;
}

.btn-na:active:hover,
.btn-na.active:hover
{
    background-color: #0099cc;
}

.btn-yes:active,
.btn-yes.active,
.btn-yes:active:focus,
.btn-yes:active.focus,
.btn-yes.active:focus,
.btn-yes.active.focus
{
    background-color: #39ac73;
}

.btn-yes:active:hover,
.btn-yes.active:hover
{
    background-color: #339966;
}

.btn-no:active,
.btn-no.active,
.btn-no:active:focus,
.btn-no:active.focus,
.btn-no.active:focus,
.btn-no.active.focus
{
    background-color: #ff8080;
}

.btn-no:active:hover,
.btn-no.active:hover
{
    background-color: #ff6666;
}

.btn-maybe:active,
.btn-maybe.active,
.btn-maybe:active:focus,
.btn-maybe:active.focus,
.btn-maybe.active:focus,
.btn-maybe.active.focus
{
    background-color: #ffdb4d;
}

.btn-maybe:active:hover,
.btn-maybe.active:hover
{
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}
```

I found a way of trying out bootstrap online here (link below). This works as intended but not elegant:

https://www.bootply.com/oBNsHuNBMx

**UPDATE 2:**
As per @juzraai's mixin solution my final scss is as follows:

```
@mixin b($c1, $c2) {
  &.active {
    &:active, &.active, &:focus, &.focus { background-color: $c1; }
    &:hover { background-color: $c2; }
  }
}

.btn {
    &.btn-na { @include b(#1ac6ff, #00ace6); }
    &.btn-yes { @include b(#53c68c, #39ac73); }
    &.btn-no { @include b(#ffb3b3, #ff8080); }
    &.btn-maybe { @include b(#ffe680, #ffdb4d); }
}
```

Working sample below:

http://jsfiddle.net/pateegutee/7nyddj8p/

Comment: And `.btn-yes:active { background-color: $colorLtGreen; }` doesn't work?

Comment: @juzraai Yes, you're right I guess I could repeat those lines of code for each button (NA, Yes, No, Maybe) but isn't that be violating DRY? I was hoping to get a more elegant scss code applying different color to each button?

Comment: I added an answer with an SCSS code which reduces repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was hoping to get a more elegant scss code applying different color to each button

Well, I would do it using a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6) and [references to parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector):

```
@mixin b($c1, $c2) {
  &:active, &.active, &:focus, &.focus { background-color: $c1 !important; }
  &:hover { background-color: $c2 !important; }
}

.btn {
    &.btn-default { @include b($colorLtBlue,  $colorBlue); }
    &.btn-na      { @include b($colorLtBlue,  $colorBlue); }
    &.btn-yes     { @include b($colorLtGreen, $colorGreen); }
    // ...
}
```

Working example:

```css
.btn.btn-default:active, .btn.btn-default.active, .btn.btn-default:focus, .btn.btn-default.focus {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
.btn.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.btn.btn-na:active, .btn.btn-na.active, .btn.btn-na:focus, .btn.btn-na.focus {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
.btn.btn-na:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.btn.btn-yes:active, .btn.btn-yes.active, .btn.btn-yes:focus, .btn.btn-yes.focus {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.btn.btn-yes:hover {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-default">default</button>
<button class="btn btn-na">na</button>
<button class="btn btn-yes">yes</button>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-default active">default</button>
<button class="btn btn-na active">na</button>
<button class="btn btn-yes active">yes</button>
```

Comment: +1 So this is how Mixins works. I have heard of it but never knew how it works and when to use it. Nice elegant solution. However, I still need to try implement this to my web app after the weekend.

Comment: Found a way to try it online. However, I can't get the mixin solution to work. What am I missing? Please check the code [here](https://www.bootply.com/qqcEKAtar2#)

Comment: @PateeGutee SCSS is not working on Bootply, it handles only CSS. Instead, you can use JSFiddle, it can handle SCSS. I copied [your code there](https://jsfiddle.net/juzraai/aa81u81f/).

Comment: I still made minor changes to get my desired result. Now it's working as intended. Please check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pateegutee/7nyddj8p/)

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks cool. :) If you need to reduce those 4 `.active` parts, you can transform them into a `&.active { ... }` block inside the mixin, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/juzraai/qdny47xn/1/). (it would also work in the `.btn` block)

Comment: That is much better! Thanks!